# Joined-наследование в SQLAlchemy без столбца-дискриминатора.

Tags: наследование, sqlalchemy, orm, sql

Нужно несколько нестандартное поведение. Есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE device (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
);
CREATE TABLE laptop (
    device_ref_id INTEGER REFERENCES device (id),
    owners_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    display_inches INTEGER
);
```

Со стороны Python есть два класса:

```
class Device(Base):
     __tablename__ = "device"

     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
     name = Column(String(30), nullable=False, unique=True)
     description = Column(Text)

     def __repr__(self):
         return "<Device '{0.name}'>".format(self)

class Laptop(Device):
    __tablename__ = "laptop"

    device_ref_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("device.id"), primary_key=True)
    owners_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    display_inches = Column(Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Laptop '{0.name}' ({0.owners_name})>".format(self)
```

В принципе, это *почти* joined-наследование из документации. Но не совсем оно.

В документации делают что — добавляют к `device` столбец `type`, который будет говорить что это такое (`'laptop'` и т.д.), и тогда все просто. У меня этого столбца **нет** и быть **не** должно.

Но, при этом, я хочу иметь возможность получить что-то в таком духе:

```
>>> session.query(Device).all()
[
    <Device 'Printer'>,
    <Laptop 'MacBook Pro' (Tim)>,
    <Laptop 'Thinkpad' (Yang)>,
    <Device 'Coffee pot'>
]
```

Проблема в том, как объяснить мапперу, чтобы он: а) делал такой запрос и б) понимал полученные данные, по наличию `laptop_device_ref_id`, что маппить ряд надо в `Laptop`, а по отсутствию — в `Device`.

Я почти этого добился: у классов указал `__mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": True}` (у `Laptop`, у `Device` — False) и сделал вот так:

```
>>> q = db_session.query(Device).with_polymorphic(
...    [Device, Laptop], discriminator=(Laptop.device_ref_id != None))
>>> q = db_session.query(Device).with_polymorphic(
...    [Device, Laptop], discriminator=(Laptop.device_ref_id != None))
>>> pprint(q.all())
[<Device 'Printer'>,
 <Laptop 'MacBook Air' (Tim)>,
 <Laptop 'ThinkPad' (Yang)>,
 <Device 'Coffee pot'>]
```

Но дискриминатор у меня бинарный, что подходит только для упрощенного примера как выше. Как бы довести его до ума?

В реальной схеме классов не два, а несколько более хитрая иерархия в духе:

```
Device
 ├─ Portable
 │   ├─ Tablet
 │   └─ Laptop
 │       └─ Netbook
 └─ Desktop
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, желательно — кусочком кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добился своего.

Суть такова:

- Добавляем в классы `polymorphic_identity`, примерно вот так:

  ```
  class Device(Base):
      __tablename__ = "device"
      __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "device"}
      …

  class Laptop(Device):
      __tablename__ = "laptop"
      __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "laptop"}
      …
  ```
- И дальше для выборки используем вот такую вот конструкцию с «виртуальным» дискриминатором:

  ```
  q = db_session.query(Device).with_polymorphic(
      [Device, Laptop],
      discriminator=case([
          (Laptop.device_ref_id != None, "laptop")
      ], else_="device")
  )
  ```

В итоге получаем правильный SQL (форматирование улучшено мной):

```
>>> print str(q)
SELECT
    device.id AS device_id,
    device.name AS device_name,
    device.description AS device_description,
    laptop.device_ref_id AS laptop_device_ref_id,
    laptop.owners_name AS laptop_owners_name,
    laptop.display_inches AS laptop_display_inches,
    CASE WHEN (laptop.device_ref_id IS NOT NULL) THEN :param_1
         ELSE :param_2 END AS anon_1 
FROM device LEFT OUTER JOIN laptop ON device.id = laptop.device_ref_id
```

И правильный результат:

```
>>> pprint(q.all())
[<Device 'Printer'>,
 <Laptop 'MacBook Air' (Tim)>,
 <Laptop 'ThinkPad' (Yang)>,
 <Device 'Coffee pot'>]
```

При добавлении новых сущностей останется добавить их классы в дискриминатор.

Единственное что, пришлось использовать все уже при запросе. С маппером у меня такой фокус  уже не получился. При попытке засунуть дискриминатор в `__mapper_args__` (через `literal_column`) он ругается на `Could not locate column in row for column 'CASE …'`. Ну это и не принципиально.